# fill inspector array automatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a two dimensional array (grid based) and want to fill this via inspector. To give you an idea about the game

[image]

So my ground script holds all those cells.

```
public class Ground : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Cell[,] cells;

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(cells);
    }
}
```

Due to the fact it would be a lot of work to manage all those cells and assign them to the ground script I thought about automating it.
So whenever I add a GameObject (as a child) and assign the Cell Component to it, the Ground should add this cell automatically to the array. To achieve this I thought about creating an editor script for the inspector.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Ground))]
public class GroundEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        Ground ground = (Ground)target;

        Dictionary<Vector2Int, Cell> cells = new Dictionary<Vector2Int, Cell>();
        int maximumHorizontalLength = 0;
        int maximumVerticalLength = 0;

        foreach (Transform groundCell in ground.transform)
        {
            Cell cell = groundCell.GetComponent<Cell>();

            if (cell != null)
            {
                Vector3 cellPosition = groundCell.position;
                Vector2Int cellIndices = new Vector2Int(Mathf.RoundToInt(cellPosition.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(cellPosition.z));
                cells.Add(cellIndices, cell);

                if (cellIndices.x > maximumHorizontalLength)
                {
                    maximumHorizontalLength = cellIndices.x;
                }

                if (cellIndices.y > maximumVerticalLength)
                {
                    maximumVerticalLength = cellIndices.y;
                }
            }
        }

        maximumHorizontalLength++;
        maximumVerticalLength++;

        ground.cells = new Cell[maximumHorizontalLength, maximumVerticalLength];

        for (int x = 0; x < maximumHorizontalLength; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < maximumVerticalLength; y++)
            {
                ground.cells[x, y] = cells[new Vector2Int(x, y)];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I want to create this two dimensional grid before starting the game to save resources. I don't want to search by tag or type while playing. And I think this approach saves time.

Unfortunately when starting the game, the Debug.Log prints null. I was hoping to populate it with this line `ground.cells = new Cell[maximumHorizontalLength, maximumVerticalLength];` Did I miss something? Is that even possible?

Comment: Given `int maximumHorizontalLength = 0; int maximumVerticalLength = 0;` how can you expect your grid to be anything but a 1x1 smashpile of every cell? (Sorta, when `x,y` exceeds max you do weird things and `ground.cells` never gets populated with anything)

Comment: @ Draco18s I'm assuming that every cell is 1x1. `and ground.cells never gets populated with anything` but I thought I can populate it with `ground.cells = new Cell[maximumHorizontalLength, maximumVerticalLength];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multidimensional arrays are [not supported by the Unity serializer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html), so you will need to restructure how you wish to store the data on each Cell. One option is to create a new custom class deriving from MonoBehaviour to store this data and place it somewhere in the Scene:

```cs
[System.Serializable]
public class CellData : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class CellReference
    {
        public int xPos;
        public int yPos;
        public Cell cell;

        public CellReference(Vector2Int posVal, Cell celVal)
        {
            xPos = posVal.x; yPos = posVal.y; cell = celVal;
        }
    }

    public List<CellReference> cellReferences = new List<CellReference>();
}
```

This can then be populated via the inspector through the following changes to your Ground and GroundEditor classes:

```cs
public class Ground : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CellData cells;

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(cells);
    }
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(Ground))]
public class GroundEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Refresh Cell References"))
        {
            Ground ground = (Ground)target;

            ground.cells.cellReferences = new List<CellData.CellReference>();

            foreach (Transform groundCell in ground.transform)
            {
                Cell cell = groundCell.GetComponent<Cell>();

                if (cell != null)
                {
                    Vector3 cellPosition = groundCell.position;
                    Vector2Int cellIndices = new Vector2Int(Mathf.RoundToInt(cellPosition.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(cellPosition.z));

                    ground.cells.cellReferences.Add(new CellData.CellReference(cellIndices, cell));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hook up the CellsData script to your placed Ground script and this will generate a new list of Cells each time the "Refresh Cell References" button is pressed in the inspector.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you do not mark the modified object as Dirty, so Unity won't save your changes. As it is a scene instance, you can either mark the entire scene Dirty or use `Undo.RecordObject(objectToUndo, name)` on the object itself. (It marks only the target object as dirty)

Using them hovewer in the `OnInspectorGUI()` is not recommended, so you might want to check for changes first and in case of any change, mark it dirty

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply. How should I use it? I tried this `Undo.RecordObject(target, string.Empty);` at the very end of the method `OnInspectorGUI` but it didn't help

Comment: It should be just before doing any changes to the object's properties. Also try to fill the second field as well

Comment: Also the other answer has right as well: Multidimensional arrays like `public Cell[,] cells;` are not supported by the Unity serializer, try to break it down to an array of objects which contains two values or such